# Field Collection Node Clone for translating nodes?

Tags: i18n-l10n, entities

I have a website with lots of field collections. When cloning a node, [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_node_clone) helps clone field collections as well, so that they don't reference the same collection. Is there anything similar for when translating nodes with [i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n)? This could be a big problem for me if not!

Comment: To clarify, you need a module that create a clone of field collection when translating the node so that each translation of the node has its own separate field collection, right ?